# ERD - Entity relationship diagram - complex and tricky relations

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

Here is the scenario.

Two completely different Entities are independently related to the third entity in the same way. How do we represent it in the ERD? or (Enhanced ER)

Ex:

- Student "BORROWS" BOOK (from the library)
- DEPARTMENT "BORROWS" BOOK (from the same library).

If I define 'BORROWS' relationship twice, it would be awkward and clumsy in terms of appearance in the diagram, and increase the complexity of implementation as well.

At the same time, I can not declare a ternary relationship since STUDENT and DEPARTMENT are not inter-related in a relationship-instance.

However, I couldn't find a better way.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Wikipedia is to be believed, [Enhanced ER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Entity-Relationship_Model) permits inheritance. Why don't you have a BORROWER entity (with the appropriate relationship), and have STUDENT and DEPARTMENT subclass that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply aix.
It definitely is a solution.
I'm just wondering about the complexity during implementation, i.e. Table creation.

If this was the case in programming context, then it'd be the most apt solution. I'm still not sure in the DB context.

Comment: @Firefox: What's the real problem you're trying to solve, other than "awkward and clumsy appearance on the diagram"?

Comment: I'm just looking for a solution less complex during implementation yet meeting all the requirements.

When I mentioned, awkward & clumsy, it was the two duplicate-relationship case, which leads to multiple tables in the DB as well.

Comment: @Firefox: relationships don't result in tables, entities do. I don't see anything wrong with having two "borrows" relationships. If that does cause problems (e.g. in the naming of foreign keys), give them slightly different names.

Comment: May be I'm missing something. But, I believe that relationship results in table. 
For ex: BORROWS relationship result in some table like BORROW_RECORD which stores foreign keys of STUDENT/DEPARTMENT and BOOK and some attributes like Start_date, etc.

Comment: @Firefox: You're right, I withdraw my previous comment: what you say is of course true for many-to-many relationships. But still, I'd just make sure that things that get generated simply get different names, that's all.

Comment: Finally, I kind of represented BORROWER entity in the ERD. Since the subclass relationship is disjoint and complete, apparently there's no need to create that BORROWER table in the DB. 
ERD (subclass, superclass etc concepts) is meant to add semantic clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue - where a company or a person can order a product.

You've got an `order`, that can belong to either a `person`, or a `company` - so what do you link the relationship to? I'm thinking orders will have a `companyId`, and a `personId` foreign key, but how do you make them exclusive? The data returned won't necessarily be the same - a `company` doesn't have a `first name` / `last name` field for example.

I guess it could be done by having a `name` returned, and in the case of a `person` build the string out of `firstname` / `lastname`, and in the case of a `company` use the `companyname` field .

Comment: I did it by generalization. For ex: in your case, I'd have created Customer table. Person & Company are its subclasses. Customer contains customerId. OrderInfo points to customerId, from which you can derive whether your orderer was a company/person.